# Ni usb gpib issue

Tags: usb

I am currently working on Debian stretch (unstable) Kernel 4.9.0-3-amd64 (latest release).

I am having problem on using a ni usb gpib. First my installation (that worked on my previous kernel) is the one adviced here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~osc22/tutorials/gpib_usb_linux.html

Here are `dmesg` when plugging in the device:

```
[73264.867644] usb 3-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 8
[73271.234223] usb 3-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[73271.344584] usb 3-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=3923, idProduct=709b
[73271.344585] usb 3-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[73271.344586] usb 3-1.3: Product: GPIB-USB-HS
[73271.344587] usb 3-1.3: Manufacturer: National Instruments
[73271.344587] usb 3-1.3: SerialNumber: 0152CFE0
[73271.344840] ni_usb_gpib: probe succeeded for path: usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3
```

Then `modprobe ni_usb_gpib` works without returning any problem.

But executing `gpib_config` returns:

```
failed to bring board online
failed to configure board
main: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Here are the related `dmesg`:

```
[73665.645045] ni_usb_gpib: attach
[73665.645047]  attached to bus interface 0, address 0xffff9b38539cd800
[73665.654427]  product id=0x709b
[73665.654431] MY_PATH/linux-gpib-4.0.3/drivers/gpib/ni_usb/ni_usb_gpib.c: usb_control_msg request 0x41 returned -11
[73665.655167] gpib: interface attach failed
```

Then, I tried to load the firmware manually, as `lsusb` has returned:

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 3923:709b National Instruments Corp. GPIB-USB-HS
```

I tried:

```
fxload -D /dev/bus/usb/003/009 -I gpib_firmware-2008-08-10/ni_gpib_usb_b/niusbb_firmware.hex  -s gpib_firmware-2008-08-10/ni_gpib_usb_b/niusbb_loader.hex
```

The firmware has been found here: http://linux-gpib.sourceforge.net/firmware/

Here are the answer:

```
write external: Connection timed out
write external: Connection timed out
write external: Connection timed out
write external: Connection timed out
write external: Connection timed out
write external: Connection timed out
unable to download usb/gpib_firmware-2008-08-10/ni_gpib_usb_b/niusbb_firmware.hex
```

and the corresponding dmesg:

```
[74612.772628] usb 3-1.3: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd fxload rqt 64 rq 163 len 208 ret -110
[74623.012617] usb 3-1.3: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd fxload rqt 64 rq 163 len 208 ret -110
[74633.252252] usb 3-1.3: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd fxload rqt 64 rq 163 len 208 ret -110
[74643.491724] usb 3-1.3: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd fxload rqt 64 rq 163 len 208 ret -110
[74653.731054] usb 3-1.3: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd fxload rqt 64 rq 163 len 208 ret -110
[74663.970461] usb 3-1.3: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd fxload rqt 64 rq 163 len 208 ret -110
```

What does this error mean? What can I do to get my usb to gpib to work?